# How do I flatten a map of map of strings in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, flatten

```
category_urls = [
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/100/0/3",
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/200/0/3",
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/300/0/3",
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/400/0/3",
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/500/0/3",
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/600/0/3"
]
result = 
  category_urls
  |> Enum.map(fn category_url ->
    1..50
    |> Enum.map(fn i -> String.replace(category_url, "/0/", "/#{i}/") end)
  end)
```

---

I'm trying to generate a map of urls I need to crawl.

The code above is generating a map of map of strings for me. I'd like to just flatten it to a simple map of strings.

How can I accomplish this in Elixir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Enum.flat_map/2`.

```
category_urls = [
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/100/0/3",
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/200/0/3",
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/300/0/3",
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/400/0/3",
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/500/0/3",
  "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/600/0/3"
]
result = 
  category_urls
  |> Enum.flat_map(fn category_url ->
    1..50
    |> Enum.map(fn i -> String.replace(category_url, "/0/", "/#{i}/") end)
  end)
  end
```

Though, use `comprehension` would make the code much simpler.

```
for i <- 1..6, j <- 1..50, do: "https://thepiratebay.org/browse/#{i}00/#{j}/3"
```